# How calculate geo bounding box from center coordinate and radius

Tags: elasticsearch, math, geometry

I have lat, long and radius of location:

```
lat = 38.7199877874397
long = -116.717434703125
radius = 6477937.81256012 - radius in metrs.
```

I need calculate geo bounding box for filtering in Elasticsearch according to this example:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html#query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query

Geo bounding box, for example should look like

```
"geo_bounding_box": {
          "pin.location": {
            "top_left": {
              "lat": 40.73,
              "lon": -74.1
            },
            "bottom_right": {
              "lat": 40.01,
              "lon": -71.12
            }
          }
```

I try use this formula:

```
(X - dX, Y - dY) and (X + dX, Y + dY)
Where:
X - longitude
Y - latitude
dY = 360 * r / R - the earth radius is R, in the same units as r
dX = dY * cos (radians (Y))
```

but i have wrong numbers:

```
((-397.59384191845777, -321.2800122125603), (164.1589725122078, 398.7199877874397))
```

How i cane calculate geo bounding box wright?
Will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Your `radius = 6477937.81256012` is close to Earth radius. Is it correct?